# how to debug annotation processor in AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, debugging, annotations

1.I write these below to file `~/User/myname/.gradle/gradle.properties`

`org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005`

2. I run `gradle --daemon`
3. I `Edit Configurations...`, add a remote debugger,and Port is 5005

finally,I rebuild project,but throws some exception:

```
Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.

Cause:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:750]
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53444791/1320616