# Trying to debug Annotation Processor in android studio end up getting exception

Tags: android, annotations, android-annotations, java-annotations

Using Android Studio 3.1.3

gradle 3.1.2

Runnung Remote build with default config with 5005 port

**and**

in gradle.properties file

org.gradle.daemon=false
org.gradle.jvmargs= -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005

always getting error:

```
Error running 'APT': Unable to open debugger port (127.0.0.0:5005): java.net.ConnectException "Operation timed out (Connection timed out)"
```

Answer (score 4):

How I made it work -

**Step 1** Run the below command in the terminal

```
./gradlew --no-daemon -Dorg.gradle.debug=true :app:clean :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
```

**Step 2**  `Go to run` -> `Edit Configurations` -> `'+'` in the top left corner -> `Remote` -> Give a name to this configuration, and ensure that the port number is 5005 -> `OK`.

**Step 3** Select your configuration from the drop-down & debug.

Comment: Worked for me only after adding `kapt.use.worker.api=true` to my `gradle.properties`

Answer (score 0):

There is an OOB way to debug gradle tasks in Android Studio:
open terminal and in you project root type

```
./gradlew :app:clean :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
```

Instead of starting it right away just press Ctrl+Shift+Enter (Execute built-in alternative in debug mode)

Android Studio will then create a new configuration and immediately start it in debug mode. Any breakpoints in your Annotation Processor will be hit as during usual debug session.

Next time you'll ever need to start debugging just select this new configuration and press Debug button next to it.